# Expose jQuery to real Window object with Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I want to expose the jQuery object to the global window object that is accessible inside the developer console in the browser. Now in my webpack config I have following lines:

```
plugins: [
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    $: 'jquery',
                    jQuery: 'jquery'
                })
            ]
```

These lines add the jQuery definitions to each file in my webpack modules.
But when I build the project and try to access jQuery in the developer console like this:

```
window.$;
window.jQuery;
```

it says that these properties are undefined...

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can I set ```this: 'window'``` too? Since many libraries assume ```this``` variable to be the Window object

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You need to use the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader).

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

You can either do this when you require it:

```
require("expose?$!jquery");
```

or you can do this in your config:

```
loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }
]
```

**UPDATE**: As of webpack 2, you need to use **expose-loader** instead of **expose**:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [{
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: '$'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: The `ProvidePlugin` should primarily used in situations where third-party libraries rely on the presence of a global variable.

Comment: I made the incorrect assumption the question was using the provide plugin for 'lazy' purposes which I have seen a lot online but you are correct :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and just to add further, for loaders, you can do it in one line too: `{test: /jquery\.js$/, loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$'}`

Comment: Just a note for others that the `require` line didn't work for me as I was getting AMD errors, but the loader-based solution did work.  That said, I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader.

Comment: Can't you just add a first script that does `$ = require('jquery'); window.jQuery = $;  window.$ = $;` ?  (not needing `expose-loader`)

Comment: When I put `{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }` in my webpack config, then try to use "$" in my code, webpack throws and "$ is not defined" error. If I use `require("expose?$!jquery");` in my code, webpack throws an error that it can't resolve jquery. However, if I use `import $ from 'jquery', everything works.

Comment: Also, be sure you have STABLE node installed and not edge. expose no like living on the edge

Comment: I had to tweak the jquery url for this to work in my setup (TypeScript 2.1.1 with jQuery 1.9.1 and Webpack 1.3.2)
`{ test: require.resolve('jquery/jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }`

Comment: According to the [expose-loader GitHub page](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader#readme) the webpack 2 syntax is as follows: 

`module: { rules: [{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), use: [{ loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'jQuery' },{ loader: 'expose-loader', options: '$' }] }] }`. 

This is the only way I could get jQuery exposed and it's using the new [module.rules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules) syntax.

Comment: @GavinSutherland I have updated the answer. I did not write the Webpack 2 edit but I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 93):

The ProvidePlugin replaces a symbol in another source through the respective import, but does not expose the symbol on the global namespace.
A classic example are jQuery plugins. Most of them just expect `jQuery` to be defined globally. With the `ProvidePlugin` you would make sure that jQuery is a dependency (e.g. loaded before) and the occurence of `jQuery` in their code would be replaced with the webpack raw equivalent of `require('jquery')`.

If you have external scripts relying on the symbol to be in the global namespace (like let's say an externally hosted JS, Javascript calls in Selenium or simply accessing the symbol in the browser's console) you want to use the [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) instead.

In short: ProvidePlugin manages build-time dependencies to global symbols whereas the `expose-loader` manages runtime dependencies to global symbols.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: ProvidePlugin example with webpack from official docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery

Answer (score 40):

Looks like the `window` object is exposed in all modules.

Why not just import/require `JQuery` and put:

```
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery;
```

You will need to ensure that this happens before requiring/importing any module that makes use of `window.JQuery`, either in a requiring module or in the module where it's being used.

Comment: Easiest solution without adding a new dependency. Thanks!

Comment: That will not work wheile other nested modules using the variable,just 'not defined'

Comment: Well it works when using `require` while not `import`

Comment: @aboutqx Not sure what you mean.  My answer assumed that JQuery had already been imported/required and assigned to a variable named `JQuery`.

Comment: @mhess  when you use `import`,you may get error,because `import`s get sorted to the top of the file, and `require`s stay where they were put. So the run-order only changes with `import` when the window varaivble is not set.

Comment: for this to work, ensure thay you did not add any jquery related DefinePlugin

Answer (score 19):

This always worked for me. including for **webpack 3** `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");`

Comment: best solution ! 2018

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me. (and I really don't like the expose-loader syntax). Instead,

I added to webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
   plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: 'jquery',
       })     
   ]
}
```

Than all modules have access through jQuery through $.

You can expose it to the window by adding the following to any of your modules bundled by webpack:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = $
```

Comment: This worked for me using webpack-stream behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Webpack v2**

Install [expose-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader) as described by Matt Derrick:

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

Then insert the following snippet in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // ...
    },
    output: {
        // ...
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
                { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery" }
        ]
    }
};
```

(from the [expose-loader docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader#readme))

Comment: I can now no longer get this to work in any version of Webpack.  Not sure what has changed but the only way I can get jQuery or $ to be recognized is to do `window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Answer (score 0):

In my case works

```
{ test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Webpack v2**

After webpack 5 upgrade, you could face this warning.

```
[DEP_WEBPACK_RULE_LOADER_OPTIONS_STRING] DeprecationWarning: Using a string as loader options is deprecated (ruleSet[1].rules[7].use[0].options)
```

Simply change the `options` to

```
options: {
 exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
}
```

will look like this:

```
module: {
rules: [{
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        {
           exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
        }
    }]
  }]
}
```