# Undefined global window variables in webpack chuncks

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack commmon chuncks to define a global library object (common components) that will be used in common with other generated bundles.

**Common code (`components.js`)**

```
MyLib = window.MayLib = {}
MyLib.Utils = {
  commonFn : function (){
    /* common code */
  }
}

module.exports = MayLib;
```

**First common usage (`dashboard.js`)**

```
   require.ensure ('./components', function () {
      MyLib.Dashboard = {
        /** Dashboad code here */
      }
   })
```

**second common usage  (`account.js`)**

```
   require.ensure ('./components', function (){
     MyLib.Account = {
       /** Account code here */
     }
   })
```

After generate bundles, a new common code has been created but `MyLib is undefined in global window, "cannot set property of undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader). See also this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack).

Although i think you can easily solve your problem by requiring the `MyLib` object inside the callback. No need to expose it to global scope anymore.

```
require.ensure ('./components', function (require){
  var MyLib = require('./components');
  MyLib.Account = {
    /** Account code here */
  }
})
```

Sidenote: You can try to simplify your code-splitting by using the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#commonschunkplugin), then you just use simple `require('components')` and the plugin is doing the rest.

Comment: Thank you @hc2p, That's right. the error come from the inner require inside the callback function, because require.ensure dosn't load the module.