# How to import globals using webpack + babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I have an application that is built using Webpack and Babel and I'm trying to import a 3rd party library that does not do an export, additionally the 3rd party library attaches itself directly on the window object.

What do I need to do in my app in order to be be able to import The3rdPartyLib?

I've tried following the loader syntax per the [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html) but it doesn't work:

```
import 3rdPartyGlobal from imports?window=>{}!exports?window.3rdPartyGlobal!3rdPartyModule
```

Comment: Take note that if you use babel, it puts ecma6 imports ahead of commonJS requires, so, it might break the order of requires in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try a similar approach found in this other question:

[Expose jquery as real window object with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack)