# jquery, webpack dll plugin and provide plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack

I use react-boilerplate, which in turn uses Webpack DllPlugin. It works great. I also use Webpack ProvidePlugin to expose jquery to automatically make jquery available in modules, so that jquery plugins can add their methods to jquery prototype as usual. It also works great. However when I put jquery into a dll file with DllPlugin, jquery becomes unavailable. I get an error

```
carousel.js:237 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Is there a solution for this problem in Webpack?

Comment: Use webpack expose loader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack