# Include jQuery in Angular2 with webpack and access it from component

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, signalr

I want to include jQuery and SignalR in my Angular2-Application and wire everything up with webpack.

I therefore installed jQuery via npm.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    // ...
  },
```

Files and folders are installed correctly.

I now target these files in my vendor.ts to get webpack to find and include them:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import '../../bower_components/signalr/jquery.signalR';
```

And webpack gets these files and wires them up. I can see this in my vendor.js. jQuery is present there. Also the jquery signalR-File.

My webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "vendor": "./wwwroot/app/vendor",
        "polyfills": "./wwwroot/app/polyfills",
        "app": "./wwwroot/app/boot"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.html']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
         new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),
        //new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["app", "vendor", "polyfills"]
        })
    ]
}
```

Loaded in my index like:

```
<script src="js/polyfills-2eba52f6.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor-2eba52f6.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-2eba52f6.bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I try to use it in my angular2 component like:

```
// ...

declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;

@Injectable()
export class MySignalRService {

    private connection;

    constructor() {

        this.connection = $.hubConnection(CONFIGURATION.baseUrls.server + 'signalr/');
        jQuery.hubConnection(CONFIGURATION.baseUrls.server + 'signalr/');

        // ...
    }

    //...
```

I alway get the message that

> $.hubConnection is not a function
>
> Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before
>   the SignalR client JavaScript file.

consoling out "$" and "jquery" is undefined.

What can I do to access the singalr-Function in webpack?

BR Tenoda

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack?

Comment: No, not yet. But i'll try that. Thank you.  If I include jQuery explicitly in index.html everything works as expected... But I will try the proposed solution...

Comment: Okay, that did not work either. Added  `
            { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" },` to my webpack.config which did not do it. THen I trief to add `import "jQuery"` in my vendor.ts which also did not work...

Comment: Can you share your project or a minimal copy on github?

Comment: It is a copy of this branch here https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNET-Core-Angular2-SignalR-Typescript/tree/AspNetCore1.0

Comment: I got jquery to work but still got "$.hubConnection is not a function"...also when i include the signalr-file...

Comment: Try this option `window.jQuery = require("jquery");` It works for me http://take.ms/cwBek See also http://take.ms/bhZKD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123056/discussion-between-tenoda-and-yurzui).

Comment: I am having this same issue. What was the final solution?

Comment: Tip: The title of the question should better be 'Include jQuery-Signalr in Angular2 with webpack'

Answer (score 8):

**Clean solution: use expose-loader !!**

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

inside your vendor.ts

```
> import 'expose?jQuery!jquery';
> import '../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js';
```

inside your webpack.config.ts

```
> new ProvidePlugin({ jQuery: 'jquery', $: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
```

Explanation:
The jquery.signalR.js script is indeed not written as a umd module. Which makes it by default, not to be loadable by webpack. The jquery.signalR.js script doesn't require jquery, but assumes that Jquery lives on the global variable window.jQuery. 
We can make this work in webpack by importing the jquery module with the expose-loader. This loader will make sure that the exported value of jquery, is exposed to the jQuery global var. Thus allowing to load the signalr.js script as the next module.

Also if you want to later use signalr by using $, you also will have to use the provideplugin for the jquery module.
inside webpack.config.js

Comment: Thank you!  Tried so many things and this is the only process that seems to work.

Comment: Thx @user547794. You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/HNeukermans/Ng2a.Frontend) with live demo.

Comment: Thanks, although which file would I add the above configuration in? Where does the webpack.config.js reside?

Answer (score 4):

I investigated your problem and found the following solutions:

1) Use

```
window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

to import jQuery in your entry file

2) Change your **webpack.config.js**

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   jQuery: 'jquery',
   $: 'jquery',
   jquery: 'jquery',
   'window.jQuery': 'jquery' <== add this line
 }),
```

And then in your entry file:

```
import 'jquery';
```

Comment: this answer in the right direction, but didn't work for me.

Comment: Warning: adding 'window.jQuery': 'jquery' added a second copy of jquery inside my bundle. Later use of the $ var did not hold the added hubConnection. using ms-signalr-client webpack 2.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with SignalR but here are the steps how I solved similar problem when trying to make  Spectrum jQuery Colorpicker work on my application:

1. Add libs into **package.json** file, dependencies section

   ```
   "jquery": "3.1.1",
   "spectrum-colorpicker": "1.8.0"
   ```
2. Add typings into **package.json** file, devDependencies section

   ```
   "@types/spectrum": "1.5.27",
   "@types/jquery": "2.0.33",
   ```
3. Specify types in **tsconfig.json** file. Compiler used to throw errors without this entry

   ```
   "types": ["jquery", "spectrum"]
   ```
4. Add webpack plugin into **webpack.common.js**

   ```
    plugins: [
           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
               jQuery: 'jquery',
               $: 'jquery',
               jquery: 'jquery'
           })
    ]
   ```
5. Add imports into **vendor.ts** file

   ```
   import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
   import 'spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum.js';
   import 'spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum.css';
   ```
6. Then in your component or directive add the following declare statement

   ```
   declare var $ : JQueryStatic;
   ```
7. Sample of usage in the code

   ```
   $("#" + this.fieldId).spectrum({
               preferredFormat: "hex3",
               showInput: true,
               showPalette: true,
               palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]],
               color: this._color,
               change: this.colorChanged,
    });
   ```

This is it. 
These modifications solved my problem and hopefully will help you and save some time to others who will try to make jQuery plugin work on Angular2 application.