# jQuery and plugins with webpack (SignalR)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack, signalr

I'm trying to use a JQuery Plugin ([SignalR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms-signalr-client)) inside my React application.

What I did is :

1. Install jquery via npm ;
2. Install the signalr client via npm ;
3. Add entries in webpack.config to specify jQuery and SignalR paths ;
4. Use `import $ from 'jquery'` and `import 'msSignalrClient'` in the React component I want to.

But that doesn't seem to work as I get this error : `jquery.signalR.min.js?dc9f:9Uncaught Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file.`

One workaround that works is to load in jQuery like this inside my `index.html` : `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`. Of course it's not optimal at all, and I'd like to import jQuery with the method I explained above. Any help appreciated !

Comment: I guess it does not matter how you include jquery. You just need to ensure that this condition https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Scripts/hubs.js#L16-L18 is being satisfied because this is how the signalr client is using jquery.

Comment: use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29083197/525788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end is this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

Answer (score 3):

this should work:

```
npm install jquery signalr expose-loader --save

//inside vendor.ts
import 'expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';
import '../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js';
```