# Can't use UIkit with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, uikit

Simply set up a project with webpack. Just install uikit with 
`npm install uikit --save`

in my main js file I use

```
import 'jquery';
import 'uikit/dist/js/uikit.js';
```

In my main html file I write below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.12/css/uikit.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<ul uk-accordion>
    <li class="uk-open">
        <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 1</h3>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 2</h3>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor reprehenderit.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 3</h3>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat proident.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

White run the npm start everything works well.. **But it says Uncaught ReferenceError: UIkit is not defined.**

[Error picture is here. click on me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzSuQ.png)

What I missing.. thanks for the help.

Comment: `import UIkit from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit.js';` ?

Comment: Tried but not working. same problem.

Comment: My github repo link is https://github.com/anamwp/style-switcher

Answer (score 3):

UIKit needs its stuff in the `window` object. So this might be the naive way to do it in `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import App from './App';

UIkit.use(Icons);

window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.UIkit = UIkit;

module.exports = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  store,
});
```

Instead, a better solution seems to be to edit the Webpack config, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083197/652626).  So, this works for me:

```
{
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$'
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve('uikit'),
    loader: 'expose-loader?UIkit'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```sh
npm install uikit --save
```

and add this to you startup script

```js
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

// loads the Icon plugin
UIkit.use(Icons);

// components can be called from the imported UIkit reference
UIkit.notification('Hello world.');
```

Official documentation here [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/docs/webpack)

A starter project here [gabihodoroaga/webpack-uikit-translate](https://github.com/gabihodoroaga/webpack-uikit-translate)

And a tutorial here [hodo.dev](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-19-webpack-with-translate/)