# import jquery into vuejs2 project via expose-loader

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I created a vuejs2 project with latest vue-cli and tried to import jQuery into the project by using expose-loader, I think I followed the instruction in the [official readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) but got no  luck.

What I've done:

- install jquery and expose-loader via npm
- insert the lines below in `build/webpack.base.conf.js`

But when I typed `console.log(window.jQuery)` in Chrome devtool's console, I still got undefined.

```
// ...
module: {
  rules: [
    // added for supporting jquery
    {
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery'
      },{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$'
      }]
    },
// ...
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You can try without the `expose-loader` using the [ProviderPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

1. `npm install jquery --save`
2. Now in your **build/webpack.base.conf.js**

   ```
   module.exports = { 
       plugins: [ 
           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
               $: 'jquery', 
               jQuery: 'jquery',
               'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
           }) 
       ]
       //..
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your advise, but I think expose-loader may be a better choice for me after reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack

Answer (score 0):

To do this in my application, I make this a bit more explicit in my entry point file directly in the import statement:

`import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';`

This exposes jquery to the `$` and `jQuery` variables via the expose-loader plugin.

Comment: Yep, `require("expose-loader?$!jquery");` can also do the trick, but I'm wondering why it doesn't work when setting it in webpack's config file.

Comment: Do you have an alias for jquery setup?  I found that the config that you are trying to use didn't work with an alias to a minified version of jquery.  If I removed the alias though, then things worked fine. The inlined version I mentioned above works just fine when I use the an alias to the minified version though.  Why this happens, not exactly sure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm sorry but I'm not sure what "alias" are you pointing at. If you mean the `alias` in the `resolve` property, here's my `resolve` property, which was defined by vue-cli and hasn't been modified by myself. `resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'], alias: {'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js', '@': resolve('src') } }`

Comment: btw, I used vue-cli's webpack template to generate my project.

Comment: Yes, the resolve.alias section is what I'm referring to.  I'm not sure what the '@' entry is for... maybe try removing it as a test to see if jquery works then.  Sorry I don't have anything more official.

Comment: '@' is used to resolve the 'src' directory. I removed it and tried again, still not working... but you've been very awesome so far, thanks a lot.