# "Export" jQuery from webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

I need to "export" jQuery library from webpack builded bundle.js file to use it in inline scripts on page (eg Google Tag Manager. A Marketer adds different scripts in it with jquery).

I don't want to add jQuery as  external library on page. I installed it with npm, import it in webpack and add in webpack.ProvidePlugin. But I still can use $, jQuery or window.jQuery only inside my bundle.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack?rq=1 might help you here

Answer (score 0):

Just put it into window object, somewhere at the top of your entry point file, before all code which require `$`, `jQuery` variable to be present

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

P.S. Provide plugin will not work in this case, library won't be available for inline scripts