# Can't resolve 'jquery' with typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack, types

I have a problem to integrate typescript with jquery in my project. I install both @types/jquery and jquery using npm, but I can't use in my .ts.
I try to import with:

```
import jquery from "jquery";
import * as $ from "jquery";
import jquery = require("jquery");
const jquery = require("jquery");
import jquery = require("@types/jquery");
```

These imports show error in compile time:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'
```

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App.ts',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'DQuiz'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    mainFields: ['browserify'],
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Comment: I have created simple project, installed `@types/jquery`, and TypeScript has compiled well without any import. Also, it works well with `import * as $ from 'jquery'`. Is your issue webpack specific?

Comment: I think is webpack specific. The problem maybe is when webpack bundle application in a unique .js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested build my project in another machine with ubuntu. I get same error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'
```

With some searchs I found a solution. For Jquery 3.x, you need to import module with **'jquery/src/jquery'**.

I use the solution suggested by Tan Duong with provide plugin, I think this solution is more elegant for jquery, then to import, you can use:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
        })
    ]
}
```

Thank you all for answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'DQuiz'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
],
```

or you can follow structure in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack)

Comment: I continue to get the same problem when run webpack: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'. I will try to execute my project in another machine to test this.