# Webpack bundles jQuery but I can't use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm a beginner with Webpack and simply stuck.
I'm trying to bundle jQuery plugins and have them in a plugins-bundled.js file.
Then I have my local scripts file where all jQuery code goes. These 2 files are loaded in HTML in order 1. plugins-bundled.js 2. scripts.js But then I got error in a console **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**. Is there something I'm missing here?

**Webpack config**

```
const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: settings.themeLocation + "js/plugins.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "plugins-bundled.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        },
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Webpack App file**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
import slick from 'slick-carousel';
import localScroll from 'jquery.localscroll';
import popper from 'popper.js';
import bootstrap from './bootstrap.min';
```

**Local scripts file**

```
(function($){    
  "use strict";    
  // code goes here...    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546793/cant-resolve-jquery-with-typescript/49547385

Comment: Why do you have a "local scripts file"?

Comment: Tried it, now  have 2 errors in console :) Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined and jQuery is not defined

Comment: @AluanHaddad I want to keep plugins and scripts in separated files.

Comment: @AluanHaddad All the JS logic will go in scripts.js, like functions etc.

Comment: @Alexander why not use modules? What's the point of taking on the complexity costs of a modern toolchain and then writing global crap?

Comment: @AluanHaddad all my code is written in functions, so it means I can't mix functional code with Webpack? I have to rewrite it in a modular way? Sorry for noob questions :)

Comment: @Alexander modules and functions are orthogonal. I'm in no way telling you to use `class`es (gods forbid). I am talking about using `import $ from 'jquery';` `export function myFunctionThatUsesJquery(args) {...}`. Anyway, even classes are functions in JavaScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad but then it'll bundle it in one file. What if I want two separated files?

Comment: @Alexander sorry I don't see what you mean. You can have as many modules as you want. Each module imports whatever it uses from other modules and exports elements that other modules can consume. You can structure your code in as many or as few files as you want.