# How to use auto-complete with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to use the jquery auto-complete plugin in a React component. 
I've installed the plugin using `npm install jquery-autocomplete --save`

Next I try to use the plugin like this in my React component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import jQuery from "jquery";
// import $ frmom 'jQuery';
import autocomplete from "jquery-autocomplete";

class AutoComplete extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.autoCompleteInput.autocomplete({
    source: ["aaa", "aab", "aac", "abb", "bbb"]
    });
  }

  state = {};

  render() {
    return <input ref="autoCompleteInput" />;
  }
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

When using this code, I get this error messages `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

What do I need to do so I can use the jQuery plugin?

Edit:
I've also tried these lines without success:

`//import { jQuery } from "jquery";
import "jquery";`

Comment: I think the proper way to import jQuery is: `import { jQuery } from 'jquery';`– see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax. That will probably not help with the plugin though, I suspect that will expect jQuery to be available in the global scope, so you'll have to do some webpack magic, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack

Comment: You're not using `jQuery` import and it's not included into a bundle. Most jQuery plugins expect a global to be there, this depends on a plugin. It likely should be `import 'jquery'`. Please, let know if this works. I'd personally advise against using jQuery autocomplete, there's a bunch of React components.

Comment: @estus See my updated answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack . This likely solves the problem.