# Jquery undefined in google maps callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, callback

My html code looks like this:

I get an error that `$` is `undefined`.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
            var input = document.getElementById('where');
            $(input).on('focus', function() { 
            selected = false;
        });
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=blablabla&libraries=places&language=en&region=CA&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried removing the `async defer`, but `$` stays `undefined`.

I tried changing the `function initialize()` for `var initialize = function()`, but `$` stays `undefined`.

I tried both, but `$` stays `undefined`.

[image]

Comment: is jquery being imported correctly? can you make sure from the network tab

Comment: @cdoshi yes, I can use Jquery in the console!

Comment: by $(input) if you mean you want to select input elements, wrap it with inverted commas $('input')

Comment: @cdoshi  I edited my question, `input` really is a variable.

Comment: ok, i see. would be best if you put up a jsfiddle or something similar. code looks ok for $ to work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonatrates your issue. The posted code gives me an (obvious) invalid key error: `Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError`, if I fix that (by removing the key) [it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20180809_jqueryIncludeIssueNoKey.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you are using jQuery in your code before even its getting loaded.
So when your jQuery code is rub at that moment '$' has no meaning.
You areavle to access  later because file is loaded after that point.
Check order of your scripts how you are loading files

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me think. I found out webpack was doing something crazy to my code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack