# Globally add $ jquery in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working with reactjs and I need to import `$` globally in my webpack.

I know I can import in each component like this

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

But it is being used in every component so I want to avoid from writing it in every component. So how do I do this using webpack or there is any other way to do this

I have added this in webpack but stills doesn't work

```
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$'
        }]
      }
    ],
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Oftopic from your question, but why would you need jquery in every component? That alone raises serious questions. Could you show a sample of the  problems that you are solving with jquery? If you do any DOM manipulation with it, then you shouldn't use reactjs at all...

Comment: I want to open the bootstrap modal popup with jquery `$('#WelcomeModal').modal('show')`. I did found something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack. But unfortunately doesn't work. Please help!!!

Comment: In every component? Can't you centralize it in your app, or on route changes?

Comment: Almost in every component.

Answer (score 1):

Use ProvidePlugin

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

```
plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: 'jquery'}) ]
```

Comment: Thank you but still it says `'$' is not defined`

Comment: Who says that? Webpack?

Comment: @HåkenLid, take a look at [webpack.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52735582/revisions)

Comment: Where do you get the error message `$ is not defined`?

Comment: in the component. When webpack completes its build creation.

Comment: Seems like it's built without the provideplugin, then. Do you use different webpack configs for development and production?

Comment: yes I have used two webpack. one for production and one for development

Comment: You must use ProvidePlugin both places.