# Webpack include jQuery in other components

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I use Webpack and my scripts is structured on this way.

```
scripts
  components
    heroSlider.js
  app.js
```

I install jQuery via npa npm and import in **app.js** like this

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

And it's work fine.
But i wan't to use jQuery in my component file. How?

In **app.js** i also import component.

```
import heroSlider from './components/heroSlider';
```

**heroSlider.js** look like this

```
export default function heroSlider() {

  // Here I wan't to use jQuery

}
```

But I don't want import jQuery again in component when i want to use it.
There is a way to do that ?

Comment: "But I don't want import jQuery again in component when i want to use it." why? It is generally advised to have explicit dependencies rather then rely on global state.

Comment: You should import it in every file you want to use it in, webpack is clever enough to only import it once if that is what you are woried about

Comment: That I wanted to hear. Tnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expose jQuery to real Window object with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery plugins that require a global jquery instance, you can **expose** `jquery` using [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader)

Once you set it up you'll be able to require it using:

`require("expose?$!jquery");`